# Ionic 2: ion-content doesnt scroll up on keyboard

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I am creating an Ionic 2 mobile app and am having some problems with input fields and keyboards. For now, I am only referring to iOS. This is the page without any input activated.

[image]

Now, If I tap on CVV or Postal Code input fields, the keyboard does not push the ion-content up so the cvv or postal code fields are in focus above the keyboard.

[image]

If I tap on postal code field, the entire input is covered by the keyboard. No scrolling happens. Before this issue, when the keyboard would open the content would squeeze up above the keyboard, but the content would squeeze, not push up off the screen if it is too large to fit the content.

Anyone have advice on how to do this? I do not think it requires any plugins to control the content or keyboards. It seems to have something to do with styling with percentages.

Comment: did solution work for you? Or have u solved it? I am having same problem.

Comment: @VivekSinha I had all of gabriels points implemented already. So, I made a focus directive so I can control the focus of each field with a boolean input value on the field. I now use that directive on every input in the app. I'll add an answer to the post soon

Comment: @pezetter Can you please post the update as I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I need to see some page code to help, but i had this problem too and solved by doing:

- Wraped all my inputs on `<ion-item>` tags.
- Used ionic input tags (not the regular `<input>` tag).
- Put all inside a `<form>` or `<ion-list>` (what you probably have done).

Without this i was having issues of fields remaining static where they are and focus errors on many input types (textarea being the one with more errors).

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling pb, i wrote a hack here : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10629#issuecomment-395084125

In the constructor of app.components.ts :

```
window.addEventListener("keyboardDidShow", () => {
    document.activeElement.scrollIntoView(false);
});
```